# How do I add a pre determined stop loss and take profit?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, pine-script

This is my first post. I am a prop trader and really trying hard to learn how to code as it would take my trading to another level. It is quite overwhelming at the beginning, but working on things that have use to me is motivating.

I have a script for trading view that I would like to edit. I have tried myself but I am obviously doing something wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated.

I just want to add my own pre determined stop loss and take profit for the strategy, The code is below:

```
strategy(title="Z-Score Strategy", shorttitle="Z-Score Strategy")
Period = input(20, minval=1)
Trigger = input(0)
reverse = input(false, title="Trade reverse")
hline(Trigger, color=purple, linestyle=line)
xStdDev = stdev(close, Period)
xMA = sma(close, Period)
nRes = (close - xMA) / xStdDev
pos = iff(nRes > Trigger, 1,
       iff(nRes < Trigger, -1, nz(pos[1], 0))) 
possig = iff(reverse and pos == 1, -1,
          iff(reverse and pos == -1, 1, pos))      
if (possig == 1) 
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if (possig == -1)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)         
barcolor(possig == -1 ? red: possig == 1 ? green : blue )
plot(nRes, color=blue, title="Z-Score")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should close the position via `strategy.exit`: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy{dot}exit

```
//@version=4
strategy("strategy")
strategy.entry("entryId", strategy.long)
strategy.exit("exitId", "entryId", profit = 5, stop=7)
```